# Lógica PHP: como construir esse looping (for, while, foreach)?

Tags: php, loop, while, for, lógica

Boa noite.

Estou na seguinte situação: estou fazendo a leitura de um XLS e jogando em table. Esse XLS tem 52 linhas e 6 colunas.

O que estou apanhando para fazer é:

```
$result[linha 1][coluna A]
$result[linha 1][coluna B]
$result[linha 1][coluna C]
$result[linha 1][coluna D]
$result[linha 1][coluna E]
$result[linha 1][coluna F]

$result[linha 2][coluna A]
$result[linha 2][coluna B]
$result[linha 2][coluna C]
$result[linha 2][coluna D]
$result[linha 2][coluna E]
$result[linha 2][coluna F]

$result[linha 3][coluna A]
$result[linha 3][coluna B]
$result[linha 3][coluna C]
$result[linha 3][coluna D]
$result[linha 3][coluna E]
$result[linha 3][coluna F]
```

E assim por diante.

Como componho esse loop? Estou tentando com for e while, mas não está rolando. Pensei em fazer com foreach, mas acho que essa opção não vai servir. Estou realmente perdido sobre como executar esse laço dentro de laço.

Abaixo está meu código. OBS: Estou usando a lib PHPExcel para fazer a leitura:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

    define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/PHPExcel.php';

    $fileName = 'file.xls';

    $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($fileName);

    $excelReader->setReadDataOnly();

    $excelReader->setLoadAllSheets();

    $excelObj = $excelReader->load($fileName);

    $excelObj->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true,true,true);

    $worksheetNames = $excelObj->getSheetNames($fileName);

    $return = array();

    foreach( $worksheetNames as $key => $sheetName ){

        $excelObj->setActiveSheetIndexByName($sheetName);

        $return[$sheetName] = $excelObj->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true,true,true);
    }

    $totalRows  = count($return['Sheet0']);
    $columns    = range('A','F');
    $colNum     = 0;
    $rowNum     = 1;
    $maxCol     = 1;

    echo '<table class="table table-responsive">';

    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<th>';

        while ( $colNum < count($columns) ) {

            echo '<td>' . $return['Sheet0'][11][ $columns[ $colNum ] ] . '</td>';
            $colNum++;

        }

    echo '<th>';
    echo '</thead>';


    echo '<tbody>';
    echo '<tr>';

    for ( $a=1; $a<=$totalRows; $a++ ) {

        if ( $rowNum <= 6 ) {

            echo  "return['Sheet0'][". $a . "][columns[" . $rowNum . "] ] " . EOL;
            //echo '</tr><tr>';

        }

        $rowNum++;
    }


    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</tbody>';

    echo '</table>';
```

Obrigado

Comment: Laço dentro do lanço

Comment: @KleberSouza não quer postar um exemplo como resposta? (se bem que do jeito que está ambígua a pergunta, corre-se o risco de nao ser isso que o autor quer).

Comment: @KleberSouza pois é, mas como fazer isso?

Comment: @Bacco estou editando, vou jogar tudo lá! Valeu

Comment: @Filipe postei uma resposta de uso geral, mas se você postarum trecho de um `print_r( $return['Sheet0'] )` posso atualizar na resposta para o caso real. Não precisa postar o resultado todo, apenas o que corresponda a uma linha e meia de dados da planilha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo de *loop* encadeado, já montando uma tabela HTML:

```
echo "<table>\n";
for ( $row = 1; $row <= $totalRows; ++$row ) {
   echo '<tr>';
   for ( $col = 1; $col <= $totalCols; ++$col ) {
      echo '<td> linha '.$row.', coluna '.$col.'</td>';
   }
   echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ZchNUr)**.

É só questão de adaptar para o que vai fazer com os dados.

<sub>Esta resposta basicamente aplica a sugestão do Kleber Souza, postada num comentário.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Um modo interessante de fazer usando recursividade com função anônima:

```
$arr['linha 1']['coluna 1'] = 11;
$arr['linha 1']['coluna 2'] = 12;
$arr['linha 2']['coluna 1'] = 21;
$arr['linha 2']['coluna 2'] = 22;
$arr['linha 3']['coluna 1'] = 31;
$arr['linha 3']['coluna 2'] = 32;

$foo = function($arr, $key = 'row') use (&$foo){
    $rs = '';
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
        $rs .= (($key == 'row')? '<tr>'.$foo($v, 'col').'</tr>' : '<td>'.$v.'</td>');
    return $rs;
};

echo '<table border="1">'.$foo($arr).'</table>';
```

Esse exemplo é para array de 2 níveis. No entanto é possível adaptá-lo para identificar níveis múltiplos e variados, sem precisar modificar o código ou especificar quantidade de colunas e linhas.